# Is WFP in Windows kernel implemented using a NDIS LWF driver?

Tags: ndis, wfp

I have a question regarding how has windows actually Implemented the WFP, and by WFP, I mean the support for writing WFP drivers.

Has this been implemented the same way as minifilter was implemented? Which in the case of minifilter, if I recall correctly, a filter driver was developed (filter manager) which had the job of simplifying the job for driver developers and added the ability to write minifilters.

My question is, was WFP implemented the same way? If so, what is the fltmgr.sys equivalent for WFP?

Based on analyzing some crash dumps and the output of ndiskd.netreport, I assume this should be wfplwfs.sys, which is the equivalent of fltmgr.sys for the file system, and its job is to distribute NBLs to WFP drivers and also assign things such as PID, etc to each NBL, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WFP is a large platform and permits callouts from many parts of the network stack. The most commonly-used callouts are at application (sockets), transport (tcp/udp), and network (ipv4/ipv6) layers. These layers are *not* implemented with an NDIS LWF drivers; they're implemented directly in tcpip.sys.

WFP also has mac layer (ethernet/wifi) callouts; in Windows 10 and Windows 11, these are implemented using an NDIS LWF driver. (This is an implementation detail, and theoretically could be changed later. Although, admittedly, I'm not sure why we would change it.)

> Based on analyzing some crash dumps and the output of ndiskd.netreport, I assume this should be wfplwfs.sys, which is the equivalent of fltmgr.sys for the file system, and its job is to distribute NBLs to WFP drivers and also assign things such as PID, etc to each NBL, correct?

Yes, for mac layer callouts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a side question, is there anyway that I can get the pid in the mac layer callout?  Because at least based on FWPS_METADATA_FIELD_PROCESS_ID, the pid is not present. I assume since its implemented using a NDIS LWF, its not possible to find the pid of each packet in the mac callout?

Comment: I'm not an expert on WFP, so I can't say if there's an easy way to get the PID in a MAC callout. In general, there's not much app info available in NDIS; it's too low level. I know some solutions use 2 callouts: a high-level one that tags packets with app/user identity, and a low-level MAC one that consumes the tags set earlier.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately I need to monitor WSL2 packets, and they bypass every WFP layer (other than the mac layer, which I assume its because this is implemented via NDIS LWF) so the only layer which their packets are available is either at the mac layer of WFP or NDIS LWF, neither of which contain the pid it seems.  Also a funny observation: WSL2 packets bypass the Windows firewall rules as well, such as a specific port blocks. I assume this is also because the Windows firewall relies on WFP instead of NDIS LWF..

Comment: From the OS point of view, I can't give any official guarantees on how to hook WSL2 traffic; it is more like an application than an OS platform with explicit extensibility points. For example, the new `experimental.networkingMode` switch will dramatically change how network packets go through NDIS. But WSL2 itself will soon offer its own firewall support as a feature - see `experimental.firewall`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/